# How to make a DIY car wash liquid

Tags: cleaning, diy, carwash

What's a good 'recipe' to make car wash liquid at home?
I have used this [product](https://www.autobarn.com.au/meguiars-gold-class-car-wash-gold-64oz-1-89l-g7164) for a while and was happy with it. The interwebs suggest:

```
1/2 cup dishwashing liquid
1/2 cup baking soda
1 gallon warm water
```

However having never made a car wash liquid am unable to comment if this is going to be effective. What is an effective, tried and test car washing liquid recipe? I don't want to be waxing after.

Comment: I heard from somewhere that you should not use much detergent when washing a car. My recipe is three or four *drops* of dishwashing liquid in a bucket of warm water: that's enough to cut the road film and lift the dirt. Hose the car with plenty of water first, sponge with soapy liquid, top down (glass first). Go round the sills etc last, then hose down, and dry off with a microfibre cloth. Finally dampen the glass again with the cloth, and buff up with a dry soft cloth. I never use wax: modern paints are much better than they were, and it is dangerous having wax on the wiped area when raining.

Comment: ...by "dishwashing liquid" I mean the thick concentrate that you squeeze into a bowl before washing dishes (by hand). With a cheap (runny) brand you need twice as much.

Comment: sensible suggestions here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/209211/97780, if not google it.

Comment: Dishwashing liquid has abrasives in it, not the best thing for keeping a smooth surface.